# navigationController toolbar won't reappear after hiding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

In my appDelegate, under **applicationDidFinishLaunching**, I have:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

In a subview, under **viewDidLoad** I have:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

However, upon hitting back on the navigation controller, the toolbar remains hidden. I've tried adding this to the **RootViewController** with no success. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where are you adding this line of code, in your RootViewController? Can you verify that it is being executed? [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

Comment: I was adding it under viewDidLoad in the RootViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `subview`, you can do following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I changed 'setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated' to 'setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES'